# how to send form data from html to web service?

Tags: c#, html, web-services, web

How to pass form data from HTML(.html) to Web service(c#) and then registers this in a database, it's possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="#">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="Text1" type="text" name="username"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="Text2" type="text" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- db contains a table with two fields username and password.
- preferably json.
- use restful.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<form id="form1" method="post" action="#">`

To `<form id="form1" method="post" action="/REST_URL/OF_YOUR_CHOICE">`

It will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `json`
But you don't need json here.

In your web service (assuming you are using asp.net) you need

**EDIT**

If you have not already done
You may need to put this in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Comment: yes i use asp.net and my url ws is example "http://localhost:5406/WebService1.asmx", then in action would. action="localhost:5406/WebService1.asmx".

Comment: Yup. And you don't need the host part if you are running in the same host. ps. this doesn't looks restful to me. :-)

Comment: you should include the method you are calling as well. For example,
`http://localhost:5406/webservice1.asmx/CaseSensitiveMethodName`